# Why can i do this in C#?(public class with ())

Tags: c#

In C# why am I able to compile and run a program with the following code

```
public class HammingTFTP()
{
     //class variables here
     public HammingTFTP(string mode, string host, string fileName)
           :this()
     {
        //code here
     }
}
```

I am coding on a mac and running mono 3.6.0. I understand there should be no () after the class declaration and i should remove :this(). Just wondering why this compiles and runs in the first place. Could it be a bug with the given version of mono?

Comment: That does not compile with the .NET compiler.

Comment: You have an `()` at the end of your class name, also **you don't have a default parameterless constructor, since you provided one with parameters in your class**, thus the error with `this`

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the `ClassName()`? It is invalid syntax.

Comment: Remove Brackets after classname and the :this()

Comment: That what i dont understand using mcs and mono 3.6.0 i am able to compile and run this on my Mac. I tested using an older version of mcs and it did not compile.

Comment: This doesn't compile with the .NET compiler, but it does with the Roslyn compiler. Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HkngI3

Comment: Primary constructors is a feature that is not staying in the final version of C# 6.  Apparently you were using a compiler that had some of the experimental features enabled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't compile with the .NET compiler, but it does with the Roslyn compiler. Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HkngI3

This is a C# 6.0 feature called "Primary Constructors". See [The New and Improved C# 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx)

It allows you to declare a primary constructor for the class alongside its declaration, such as:

```
public class MyClass(string name)
{
    public string Name {get; } = name;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Interesting how it compiles on some compilers and not other.

Comment: @user3024509: That is called: 'new specs'.

Comment: @user3024509 The C# 6.0 spec is pretty recent, some compilers don't support it *yet*. I'm actually not even sure whether the spec is in its final version.

Answer (score 1):

Mono 3.6.0 already supports some of the features that will come in C# 6.0, as stated [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/).

In your case this is namely primary constructors. See [this language preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx) for more details.

Without using primary constructors, your code would translate as follows:

```
public class HammingTFTP
{
    // generated via primary constructor
    public HammingTFTP()
    {
    }

    //class variables here
    public HammingTFTP(string mode, string host, string fileName)
       :this()
    {
       //code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. Nice to know im not crazy.